# Error reading edit log in hadoop namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I am using 3 node hdfs cluster, it was running fine from past few months but from few days i am getting below exception in the logs frequently in one of the namenode, it was Active node but due to this error hdfs failover itself to secondary namenode, although things are fine but i want to resolve this issue, please suggest:-

```
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage$HttpGetFailedException: Fetch of http://nn1.cluster.com:8480/getJournal?jid=ha-cluster&segmentTxId=827873&storageInfo=-63%3A1513620929%3A0%3ACID-c43f63a9-b064-4dc6-b175-378bf0db96e3 failed with status code 500
Response message:
No realm
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog$1.run(EditLogFileInputStream.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog$1.run(EditLogFileInputStream.java:456)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsUser(SecurityUtil.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsCurrentUser(SecurityUtil.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog.getInputStream(EditLogFileInputStream.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.init(EditLogFileInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.nextOpImpl(EditLogFileInputStream.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.nextOp(EditLogFileInputStream.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.skipUntil(EditLogInputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.skipUntil(EditLogInputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadFSEdits(FSEditLogLoader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer.doTailEdits(EditLogTailer.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.access$200(EditLogTailer.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread$1.run(EditLogTailer.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.run(EditLogTailer.java:297)
2016-10-14 01:38:32,375 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream: Got error reading edit log input stream http://nn1.cluster.com:8480/getJournal?jid=ha-cluster&segmentTxId=827873&storageInfo=-63%3A1513620929%3A0%3ACID-c43f63a9-b064-4dc6-b175-378bf0db96e3; failing over to edit log http://nn2.cluster.com:8480/getJournal?jid=ha-cluster&segmentTxId=827873&storageInfo=-63%3A1513620929%3A0%3ACID-c43f63a9-b064-4dc6-b175-378bf0db96e3
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream$PrematureEOFException: got premature end-of-file at txid 827872; expected file to go up to 827874
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.skipUntil(EditLogInputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadFSEdits(FSEditLogLoader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer.doTailEdits(EditLogTailer.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.access$200(EditLogTailer.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread$1.run(EditLogTailer.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.run(EditLogTailer.java:297)
```

Comment: Does required space is available in that machine?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your namenode is corrupted. Try to recover it using the following command

```
hadoop namenode -recover
```